# How to get "Sound+Brightness" menu in Kubuntu / KDE

Tags: kde, kubuntu

I have been trying to get "system menu" with (Sound+Brightness) slider similar to GNOME on my (KDE) desktop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPNRL.png

After I enable setting volume, brightness and network-related on my KDE PLASMA. but still can't get the (brightness+sound slider) merging together in one drop down menu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLy3C.jpg

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: Each DE organizes controls their own way.  Some of those little dashboards are designed by the DE project as part of the DE user interface.  The rest are applets that other people designed and contributed to combine functions they thought would be useful together.  If you want one for Plasma and it isn't part of the DE, look at the applets available for download.  You may have luck.  Otherwise, how are your programming skills?  :-)